# ¿Cómo puedo cambiar el color de mi textView al presionar una fila de mi spinner personalizado?

Tags: java, android-studio, kotlin, spinner, android-spinner

Estoy trabajando en un spinner personalizado,yo deseo presionar una de las fila y esta a su vez me permita cambiar el color de los  textViews con los cuales estoy trabajando , el problema es que al presionar una de sus filas no pasa nada, lo he intentado de esta manera no he podido.

```
val lista = listOf<Mood>(
    Mood(resources.getColor(R.color.blue, null), "Color1"),
    Mood(resources.getColor(R.color.purple, null), "Color2"),
    Mood(resources.getColor(R.color.green, null), "Color3"),
    Mood(resources.getColor(R.color.darkred, null), "Color4")
)

val adaptador = MoodArrayAdapter(this, lista)
spinner1.adapter = adaptador

spinner1.onItemSelectedListener = object :
    AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
    override fun onItemSelected(p0: AdapterView<*>?, p1: View?, p2: Int, p3: Long) {
        when (spinner1.selectedItem.toString()) {
            "Color1" -> textView.setBackgroundResource(R.color.blue)
            "Color2" -> textView.setBackgroundResource(R.color.purple)
            "Color3" -> textView.setBackgroundResource(R.color.green)
            "Color4" -> textView.setBackgroundResource(R.color.darkred)
        }
    }
    override fun onNothingSelected(p0: AdapterView<*>?) {
        TODO("Not yet implemented")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Estás utilizando el método `setBackgroundResource`, deberías utilizar `setBackgroundColor` o `setTextColor` si lo que quieres es cambiar el color del texto.